# How to get token in OpenID connect flow in C sharp api?

Tags: c#, api, openid-connect

My API uses OIDC flow to get access it's method. OIDC should return an id token and an access token.
When I run the controller, I am sent to the authentication page where I have to enter my login credentials. When login is successful, I am redirected back to my controller url - e.g localhost:41223/api/Identity/GetInformation.

My controller method is as below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult<int> GetInformation()
    {
       var information = User.Claims;
       return 1;
     }
```

The id token should include authenticated user information which is available with the code below:

```
User.Claims;
```

How do I retrieve the access token information and decode it to get the token expiration time? From my research, we have to decode the token at https://jwt.io/. But how do we actually get the token in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code to get access to the raw tokens

```
        string idToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token").Result ?? "";
        string accessToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result ?? "";
```

For this to work you must also set this to true

options.SaveTokens = true;

Then to parse the token you can read more about that [here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/01/15/creating-and-validating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core/)